# dotnet bundle not working in .net core mvc application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I try to use bundleconfig.json, which is standard added to the project when I started the project. I read every where they say you have to run

```
dotnet bundle
```

But this is not working for me I get the error

> No executable found matching command "dotnet-bundle"

Now I Googled and found that I have to add this in Project.json

```
 "tools": {
"BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.281",
```

But I have no Project.json file only csproj. I thought I have to install package. So I installed BundlerMinifier.Core but still same error.

What do I have to do so I can run the code and bundle my files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=netcore-cli%2Caspnetcore2x you have to install the CLI tools for dotnet to do this.

From a command line in the project directory it looks like you do this:

```
dotnet add package BuildBundlerMinifier
dotnet build
```

and you should get this result

```
 Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.4.8.50001 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Bundler: Begin processing bundleconfig.json
Bundler: Done processing bundleconfig.json
BuildBundlerMinifierApp -> C:\BuildBundlerMinifierApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\BuildBundlerMinifierApp.dll
```

The linked page also talks about ad-hoc bundling. Its on the microsoft site so it *shouldn't* go anywhere.

Comment: Thank you. the documentation page does not mention needing to add that nuget package, at least for .net 3+

Comment: Still true in 2020 for asp.net-core 3.1. The documentation mentions this under the Gulp tasks section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-3.1#run-gulp-tasks